Windows 10 reset operation stuck on black screen with spinning dots
I wanted to do a full reset of my Windows 10 without keeping any file or app on main disk, so I used the Windows reset feature, but now after seeing the "MSI" logo, I can see only white dots spinning for ever.
What are my options to get back the access to my PC since I don't have any CD ROM (I don't even have a CD ROM reader on this PC) ?
Can I download some USB recovery tool ? Will it be able to detect I had a valid licence on my PC ?
Any help is welcome, I'm quite desperate right now  :/

The WIndows 10 license is automatically detected on OEM devices.  You will need another Windows, in order to create a Windows 10 installation media, by using the Media Creation Tool

Ok thanks, that's a good news. Now the only device I have access is using Ubuntu, I was able to download the "Media Creation Tool" iso from it, but how to create the bootable USB from it ?

You run it. You made no reference to the fact your using Linux

What do u mean I "run it" ? I can mount it and see the file in it, that's it I can't "run" a .exe on Linux.

Ok, I've copied the iso files to USB key formatted in NTFS, and now I have a bootable USB key. I've followed this method : https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/

Just copying the contents of a Windows ISO isn’t enough to make it bootable and the WinPE functional

yes it is enough, if it's a NTFS formatted USB key
